# Issue on Vscode Terminal in MacOS Monterey

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, macos-monterey

i just start coding on my first project in python and then this happen for the first time in my VsCode

[image]

i have no idea why this is happening , please help me

Comment: Have you modified the `terminal.integrated` related configuration in the settings.json file? such as `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` and so on.